# Is it possible to search in Craft Commerce by product type?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, query, querystring

I am building an API that takes all products from the Craft Commerce `Commerce_ProductModel`. In this I am using the Element API plugin to build it out. I am running on Craft 2 latest version.

I have so far built out the JSON API and it's returning what I need with the following code:

```
'api/allproducts' => [
    'elementType' => 'Commerce_Product',
    'criteria' => [
        'search' => buildSearchQuery(craft()->request->getParam('types'))
    ],
    'transformer' => function(Commerce_ProductModel $product) {

        $mergedProductData = [];

        $title = $product->title;
        $url = UrlHelper::getUrl($product->url);
        $brand = (string)$product->productBrand[0];
        $designer = (string)$product->productDesigner[0];
        $num_decimals = (intval($product->defaultVariant->price) == $product->defaultVariant->price) ? 0 :2;
        $price = number_format($product->defaultVariant->price,$num_decimals);

        $frontImage = $product->productImages[0];
        $frontImages = [];

        if ($frontImage)
        {
            craft()->config->set('generateTransformsBeforePageLoad', true);

            if (craft()->plugins->getPlugin('Imager'))
            {
                $transformedImages = craft()->imager->transformImage(
                    $frontImage,
                    array(
                        array(
                            'width' => 1170,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'width' => 780,
                            'jpegQuality' => 65,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'width' => 390,
                            'jpegQuality' => 65,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'ratio' => 16/9,
                        'position' => 'bottom-right',
                        'jpegQuality' => 80,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'fillTransforms' => true,
                    )
                );

                $frontImages[] = craft()->imager->srcset($transformedImages);

            } else {
                $frontImages[] = $frontImage->getUrl(['width' => 390, 'height' => 294]);
            }
        }

        $mergedProductData[] = [
            'id' => $product->id,
            'title' => $title,
            'productImage' => $frontImages,
            'body' => (string) $product->body,
            'brand' => $brand,
            'designer' => $designer,
            'url' => $url
        ];

        return [
            'title' => $title,
            'id' => $product->id,
            'frontImage' => $frontImages,
            'type' => $product->type->name,
            'designer' => $designer,
            'brand' => $brand,
            'price' => $price,
            'url' => $url,
            'isInWishlist' => craft()->like->isLike($product->id),
            'quickViewJson' => $mergedProductData
        ];
    },
],
```

This is great, its returning what I need and its nothing more but I am trying to return search values against it by looking for the product type form the `Commerce_ProductModel` and its hard to figure out.

What I ideally want to do is run a URL query like so:

`/api/allproducts?types[]=New&types[]=Tables`

In the code above there is this function that I was given by another developer that allows you to build queries like the URL above.

`buildSearchQuery(craft()->request->getParam('types'))`

In this I want to be able to query any `product type` from Craft Commerce so it only returns products of these types. The function is below:

```
function buildSearchQuery($input) {

    $query = "";
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($input as $value) {

        if($i > 0) {
            $query .= " OR ";
        }

        $query .= "title:*$value* OR body:*$value*";
        $i++;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on how this can be done at all?

Answer (score 1):

Products can be queried by the product types `type` (a handle or ProductTypeModel) or `typeId` the ID of the type.

In a template this would look like:

```
craft.commerce.products.typeId([1,3,4]).find()
```

or

```
craft.commerce.products.type(['new','another']).find()
```

This is as per the parameter value syntax: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax

So in an element criteria query syntax in PHP it would look like this:

```
'criteria' => [
  'type' => ['New','Another']
],
```

or

```
'criteria' => [
  'typeId' => [1,2]
],
```

or

```
'criteria' => [
  'type' => craft()->commerce_productTypes->getAllProductTypes()[0]
],
```

The example you can was to build a query string for the search element criteria param, which could optionally be another criteria if you wanted.

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the detailed explanation. I just need a little clarity about using my search criteria for the url.

If the structure of the url above that I showed was used in my search criteria how could we build the queries in? Would I add it into the function? `buildSearchQuery()`